# am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'config.onComplete') when trying to listen to keyboard event in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';

```
Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillShow',
      keyboardWillShow
    );
```

am trying to listen to the keyboard events willShow and willHide and then do something about the events

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function, it returns a boolean based on if the keyboard is open or not, and you can add actions to it

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';

export function useKeyboard() {
  const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillShow',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true); // or some other action
      },
    );
    const keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillHide',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false); // or some other action
      },
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
      keyboardWillShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return isKeyboardVisible;
}
```

Comment: thank you , this seem to fix my problem, but i sill don't understand why it was throwing that error

Comment: Cause you should have placed it inside of a useEffect, and add the .remove() function.